# Conversão de binario para decimal

Tags: haskell

Fiz um algoritmo que converte do Binário para o Decimal, agora preciso desenvolver um que faz o contrario. Vou deixar o código que fiz abaixo, porém esta com erro. Obrigado.

```
converte' :: [Int] -> Int
converte' [] = 0
converte' (x:xs) = ((2 ^ comprimento xs) * x) + (2 ^ (comprimento xs-1)) * x
```

ps: função `comprimento` mede o tamanho da cauda da lista atual

Answer (score 0):

Você não postou sua função `comprimento`, então usei as funções `length` e `tail` do Haskell.

Uma possível função para converter decimal para binário:

```hs
decParaBin 0 = [0]
decParaBin 1 = [1]
decParaBin x = decParaBin (x `div` 2) ++ [x `mod` 2]
```

Você não postou sua função que converte binário para decimal, então também fiz uma:

```hs
binParaDec [] = 0
binParaDec x = head x * 2 ^ (length x - 1) + binParaDec (tail x)
```